# Citrix VDI-In-a-Box Taking "Milestone Snapshots"

Tags: xenserver, citrix, vdi, xen

We're using Citrix VDI-in-a-Box, with XenServer on the back-end. I noticed in one of my deployed images, either XenServer for VDI in a box is creating snapshots automatically. The snapshots are listed as `"ComputerName"Milestone (snapshot)`.

[image: Snapshots Tab in XenCenter]

This is only happening for one set of images from a common published template. I have three other templates with associated images that are not producing automatic snapshots.

I went through the VM settings with XenServer, and through the template settings in VDI in a box, to no avail. Googling this issue seems to only come up with Citrix's milestone information for their own development.

My end goal would be to have these automatic milestone snapshots not created. Until then, I manually delete the snapshots. I don't have a need for the snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! VDI-In-A-Box includes a setting called "Fast Desktop Refresh" which changes the way that desktop refreshes happen.

If Fast Refresh is not enabled, the desktop is destroyed and recreated from the template.

If fast refresh is enabled (as it was in my case), VDI-in-a-Box creates a pre-login snapshot to refresh to, rather than actually ever destroying the desktop.

I've changed my refresh strategy, and all seems to be well!